# Is there a way of synchronizing what a <td> element says across multiple devices?

Tags: javascript, html

The table is on a repo. The table is blank, but users can upload info into the `<td>` cells by a text space and button function.

```html
<input type=“text” id=“one”>
<button onclick=“upload()”>
```

JavaScript

```js
function upload(){
  this.disabled = true
  document.getElementById(“targetTDElement”).innerText = document.getElementById(“one”).value
}
```

By synchronizing, I mean by when user A uploads some information into the table using device A user B can also find that information on the table on device B. Basically like this website. Someone posts a question, and it becomes synchronized and visible on other devices.

How is this done?

Comment: Huh?  WHat do you mean by "device"?  This question makes no sense.  Sorry.

Comment: Yes, it is possible but you need to use XHR to submit data to your server and then websockets or similar on device B to see if any changes has happened and update accordingly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are Long-Polling, Websockets, Server-Sent Events (SSE) and Comet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet)

Comment: unfortunately, no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have the main server to do so, simple solution is a polling mechanism :

client post:

```js
function upload(){
  this.disabled = true
  postDataToRemoteServer({one:document.getElementById(“one”).value});
}
```

client poll:

```js
setInterval(()=>getDatafromServer().then(data=>{
   document.getElementById(“one”).value = data.one
},1000)
```

server skeleton

```
@post
save(data){
  //save data to database <- postDataToRemoteServer calls this
}

@get
get(){
//get data from database <- getDatafromServer calls this
```

}

Comment: Exactly  what I wanted. I’m gonna test this out. Thank you